# Intellij IDEA unable to resolve appengine-maven-plugin dependency

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I created a new google appengine java project using `mvn archetype:generate`, as specified in [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven) page.

I executed `mvn clean install` and project got successfully built.

But, when I opened the project with Intellij IDEA, it indefinitely keeps on resolving dependencies. Only when I comment out the `appengine-maven-plugin` plugin dependency, IDEA completes the dependency resolution.

What could be the cause for IDEA being unable to resolve `appengine-maven-plugin` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what fixed the issue, but after following commands, it worked.

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
mvn appengine:devserver
```